# Sequence operators not supported for type 'System.String'.

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

There is a composite primary key on the columns in the where condition of the below code so there can be only one possible return value. I am returning by `SingleOrDefault`  but at run time I am getting the error in the question title: "Sequence operators not supported for type 'System.String'." I'm pretty new to LINQ so might have got the syntax wrong? Any help appreciated

```
 using (myContext Data = new myContext())
    {
        string Result = (from d in Data.myTable 
                    where d.textColumn == myDropDownList.SelectedValue && d.intColumn == 1
                    select d.anotherTextColumn.SingleOrDefault()).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I think you're calling SingleOrDefault on the wrong thing, inside the parens instead of outside. What about this: select d.anotherTextColumn**)**.SingleOrDefault()

Comment: dotnetom's answer is right, but in case you're wondering, you can't call ToString in a linq-to-entities query because that query has to get translated to sql rather than being executed like normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there - you need to call `SingleOrDefault()` on the query object instead of calling it on `string` object:

```
string Result = (from d in Data.myTable 
                where d.textColumn == myDropDownList.SelectedValue && d.intColumn == 1
                select d.anotherTextColumn).SingleOrDefault();
```